# rails 4 nested form belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables, including nested form association as shown in the following models and while try to save,it doesn't save in Phone table.

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :phone

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['N'].blank? }
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :phones, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :activities

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['phone_number'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :activities
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many   :activities

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :activities
end
```

and in ActivitiesController

```
def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    @activity.customer = Customer.new
    @activity.phone = Phone.new
end

def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:activityDate, :customer_id, :phone_id, :details, customer_attributes:  [:id, :name, phone_attributes: [:id, :phone_number]])
end
```

Note =>
I have in my Activity table customer_id, phone_id just for performance

in Activity _form

```
 <!-- Nested form customer -->
    <%= f.fields_for :customer do |builder| %>
      <%= render "customer_fields", x: builder %>
    <% end %>
```

in customer partial

```
<div class="field form-group">
      <%= x.label "Customer name" %>
      <%= x.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<%= x.fields_for :phone do |builder| %>
      <% 3.times do %>
            <%= render "customers/phone_fields", f: builder %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in the last phone partial

```
<%= f.label :phone_number %>
<%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
```

Why I can't save Phones in this nested

Answer (score 3):

As per `Zozo`'s answer, you'll need to build the associated objects as follows:

```
def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    @activity.build_customer.phones.build
end
```

There's an added step you need to consider... you're embedding your `phone` fields inside your `customer` fields. This means that you'll have to build the associative models as they are associated:

```
#app/models/activity.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :phone
   belongs_to :customer
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer 
end

#app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :phones
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones
end
```

This is *only* necessary if you want to embed the `fields_for` like you have:

```
#app/controllers/activities_controller.rb
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @activity = Activity.new
      @activity.build_customer.phones.build
   end
   def create
      @activity = Activity.new activity_params
      @activity.save
   end

   private

   def activity_params
       params.require(:activity).permit(:x, :y, :z, customer_attributes:[ phones_attributes: [:phone, :attributes] ])
   end
end

#app/views/activities/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @activity do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :customer do |x| %>
      <%= x.fields_for :phones do |phones| %> #-> see how you're embedding this inside the original fields_for?
         <%= phones.text_field %>
      <% end %> 
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

To do it normally, you'd have to just build the associative data as separate objects:

```
#app/models/activity.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer
   belongs_to :phone

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer, :phone
end

#app/controllers/activities_controller.rb
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @activity = Activity.new  
       @activity.build_customer
       @activity.build_phone
   end
end

#app/views/activities/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @activities do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :customer do |customer| %>
      <%= customer.text_field .... %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.fields_for :phone do |phone| %>
      <%= phone.text_field .... %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

I almost forgot, there's something else...

```
<% 3.times do %>
    <%= render "customers/phone_fields", f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

**VERY** BAD PRACTICE.

If you want 3 sets of `fields_for` to load, you need to *build* the object 3 times, eg:

```
def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    3.times do
       @activity.build_phone
    end
end

<%= form_for @activity do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :phone do |f| %>
      This will appear 3 times
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is called perfect answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks buddy!! Hope it helped

Comment: It helps a lot my friend.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity.new`, `Customer.new` and `Phone.new` create instances of the respective classes and don't save them to the database. To do that after manipulating the created objects you have to call `save` method. For example `@activity.save`.